# Variable within ssh.scp.download

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby script I am trying to call a variable within :

```
ssh.scp.download!("VARIABLE GOES HERE", "/localpath/")
```

Just cannot get the right syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: http://net-ssh.github.com/scp/v1/api/classes/Net/SCP.html#M000012 your variable needs to be a remote path to a resource.
There is no secret, just 2 strings representing remote and local path.

```
ssh.scp.download!("/removepath/", "/localpath/")
```

or

```
data = ssh.scp.download!("/removepath/")
```

Comment: Yah it is, but Im struggling to get the ssh.scp.download to recognize the variable when I place it in the "remote path" section. So for example :

variable =  ssh.exec!('ls /path/to/file')
How would I place "variable" in :
ssh.scp.download! "variable", "/usr/local/mxit/rpm"

Everything I have tried has failed.

Comment: Maybe the output from your exec! is not a valid arg to the download! method. If i am not mistaken, your call to exec list all files in a directory, as the first parameter of the download method requires to be a full path to a file.

Comment: Im using a wildcard to get the desired file and have tested the output of my exec! command. I think it is struggling to insert the variable with quotations.